# Отправить информацию из Google таблицы в corezoid

Tags: google-apps-script, webhook

Помогите отправить из Google Script информацию в коризоид, где указывать вебхук надо?

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var result = {"result":"ok"};


  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);


}
```

Когда заявка прилетает из каризойда, скрипт ниже нормально работает

```
function doGet(request) {

   var row = [];
   row.push(request.parameter.column1); // Значение для 1-го столбца
   row.push(request.parameter.column2); // Значение для 2-го столбца
   row.push(request.parameter.column3); // Значение для 3-го столбца

   // И так далее для всех столбцов, в порядке в котором они указаны в таблице

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet_id") // ID - таблицы
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_name"); // Имя листа в который добавлять данные
   sheet.appendRow(row);

   var result = {"result":"ok"};

   return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var payload = 
   { 
   "test": "test",
   "test2": "testing"
   };

   var options = 
   {
     "method" : "post", 
     'contentType': 'application/json',
     "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
     "muteHttpExceptions" : true
   };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("***URL - url процесса в корезоиде***", options)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает